# AWS SDK - support for custom truststore

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk, truststore

We use multiple truststore in our application and need a way to set a specific truststore for AWS SDK (S3 client implementation) to connect to S3 server.
Currently, we are getting a cert chain exception when we try to connect to the S3 Server. Reason being the respective root certificate is not there in default truststore.
Instead of that we want to set the correct truststore explicitly for AWS SDK(S3 client implementation).

We looked into AWS SDK library and could not figure out as how can we set a custom truststore and not through jvm property.

Comment: There are several AWS SDKs. Which SDK for which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I've never did something like that. However - from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm-pca/latest/userguide/PcaExternalRoot.html) it should be possible. So if you have your own CA, you can register keys at AWS side, so key/certificate will be accepted.

On the other hand, I'm not 100% sure if I'm getting your problem correctly... Usually, when I use AWS S3, I'm connecting over https from my client to their host. Can you please elaborate more on that S3 client and server? Maybe there is other solution - if so - I'll edit answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the solution for adding custom keystore to the HTTP request. Idea is to import all the keystore programmatically and add it as part of apache client config. Below is the code snippet used.

```java
private static AmazonS3 createClient(Properties prop) throws KeyManagementException, UnrecoverableKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, IOException {
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(prop.getProperty("access.key"),prop.getProperty("secret.key"));
    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
    if(prop.getProperty("proxy.host")!=null && !prop.getProperty("proxy.host").equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        clientConfiguration.setProxyHost(prop.getProperty("proxy.host"));
    if(prop.getProperty("proxy.port")!=null && !prop.getProperty("proxy.port").equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        clientConfiguration.setProxyPort(Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("proxy.port")));
    if(prop.getProperty("proxy.username")!=null && !prop.getProperty("proxy.username").equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        clientConfiguration.setProxyUsername(prop.getProperty("proxy.username"));
    if(prop.getProperty("proxy.password")!=null && !prop.getProperty("proxy.password").equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        clientConfiguration.setProxyPassword(prop.getProperty("proxy.password"));
    
    
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keyStore.load(null, null);
    CertificateFactory fact = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream ("entrust_g2_ca.cer");
    X509Certificate cer = (X509Certificate) fact.generateCertificate(is);
    is.close();
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ssl-ca", cer);
    
    TrustManagerFactory tmFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmFactory.init(keyStore);
    TrustManager[] tms = tmFactory.getTrustManagers();
    SecureRandom sr = getRandomWithoutSeed();
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, tms, sr);
    SdkTLSSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SdkTLSSocketFactory(sslContext , null);
    
    clientConfiguration.getApacheHttpClientConfig().setSslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
    
    
    AmazonS3ClientBuilder s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withEndpointConfiguration(new EndpointConfiguration(prop.getProperty("s3.endpoint"), prop.getProperty("s3.region")))
            .withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration);
    if(credentials!=null) {
        s3Client.withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials));
    }
    return s3Client.build();
}
```